# Styles in TikZ trees not working as expected

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-trees

I want to draw a "cut-out" region of a tree, and visually underline this by having dashed edges on top and on the bottom of my diagram (to symbolize the levels further up and further down).

I am attempting to use styles defined in the options of the `\tikzpicture` environment, but failing to achieve the desired result, which would look something like this:

[image: desired result]

For me, the "outermost" edges (which I want to be dashed) are just normal lines.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style={minimum size=4mm, inner sep=0.5mm},
  normal/.style={circle,draw},
  invis/.style={draw=none},
  border/.style={ edge from parent/.style={dashed,draw} },
  acc/.style={circle,thick,draw=green!50,fill=green!2},
  rej/.style={circle,thick,draw=red!50,fill=red!20},
  semithick]

  node[invis] (root) {}
    child[level distance=11mm] { node[border,normal] {x}
      child {node[acc] {x1}
        child {node[border,invis] {} }
        child {node[border,invis] {} }
        child {node[border,invis] {} }
      }
      child {node[rej] {x2} }
      child {node[normal] {x3}
        child {node[invis,border] {} }
        child {node[invis,border] {} }
        child {node[invis,border] {} }
      }
  }; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My first hunch was maybe a node could only have one style defined in its options, but even after swapping the two styles for the last tree nodes, it makes no difference. I also tried applying a style and setting an option in the same []-block, and it worked, so this doesn't seem to be the problem.

I am aware that the author of TikZ notes in the manual that "placing node options at the right place is an arcane art", but (after carefully reading) I thought basically it worked like this:

- Options defined in a `node` are local in effect.
- Options defined in a `child` command are inherited to all of its child nodes.

When trying to pass the `border` style to the `child` command as an alternative , I **do** get dashed edges which work for the bottom, but if I pass it to the first visible child node (x), all the lines in the tree are dashed (even the node outlines!) because of the inheritance mechanism.

What am I doing wrong/ should I change to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Hi MHaaZ, could you provide a picture to clarify exactly what you're aiming for? Hand-drawn and scanned in would be fine. You don't have sufficient reputation yet to include pictures in your posts, but if you upload it to http://www.imgur.com and then post the link here in the comments, then somebody will insert the picture on your behalf.

Comment: Also, it's better to post a complete `.tex` document, rather than just a snippet. Otherwise, I have to type out the `\begin{document}` stuff myself, which isn't much fun! `:-)`

Comment: I am currently on the road, will do as soon as I get to campus :)

Comment: @John Wickerson Here it is: http://imgur.com/NgKxzUm
Thanks for the remark on the whole `.tex`, will edit question and remember for the future! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a quick demonstration with Forest. The major advantages of Forest lie in its power, flexibility and concise syntax. Regularities in content and styling can be turned into automated configuration rules and trees themselves can be specified very concisely. Since Forest is based on Ti*k*Z, the power of the host package is also available.

For example,

```
\begin{forest}
  bordered tree,
  [
    [x, border
      [x1, acc, for descendants=border
        [][][]
      ]
      [x2, rej]
      [x3, for children=border
        [][][]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

specifies the target tree:

[image: target tree]

while the following partly explains the first and partly shows one or two additional tricks,

```
\begin{forest}
  bordered tree,
  [
    [x, border, normal
    [x1, acc, for descendants=border, label=left:\texttt{for descendants}
        [][.,label=left:bordered children [][]][]
      ]
      [x2, rej]
      [x3, normal, for children=border, label=right:\texttt{for children}
        [][.,label=right:unbordered children [][]][, for current and ancestors={edge+=blue}]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

which produces:

[image: annotated tree]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  declare boolean={border}{0},
  bordered tree/.style={
    for tree={
      minimum size=4mm, 
      inner sep=0.5mm,
      edge+={semithick},
      semithick,
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      where border={
        edge+={dashed, draw},
      }{},
      where={isodd(n_children)}{
        tempcounta/.process={
          Ow+n {n children}{(##1+1)/2}
        },
        for n={
          >  R {tempcounta} % doesn't work to plug the above in directly ??'
        }{calign with current edge},
      }{},
      where content={}{}{normal},
    },
  },
  /tikz/.cd,
  normal/.style={circle,draw},
  invis/.style={draw=none},
  acc/.style={circle,thick,draw=green!50,fill=green!2},
  rej/.style={circle,thick,draw=red!50,fill=red!20},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  bordered tree,
  [
    [x, border
      [x1, acc, for descendants=border
        [][][]
      ]
      [x2, rej]
      [x3, for children=border
        [][][]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  bordered tree,
  [
    [x, border, normal
    [x1, acc, for descendants=border, label=left:\texttt{for descendants}
        [][.,label=left:bordered children [][]][]
      ]
      [x2, rej]
      [x3, normal, for children=border, label=right:\texttt{for children}
        [][.,label=right:unbordered children [][]][, for current and ancestors={edge+=blue}]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why distance between x2 and x3  is larger than distance between x1 and x2? trees below x1 and x3 are similar, so, why the tree is not symmetric?

Comment: @Ignasi Because I thought it looked better when the edge to the second one was aligned with the parent than when they were equally spaced. The default is equal spacing, but I prefer the middle child aligned in many (not all) cases.  Just remove the `where={isodd(n_children)}` clause which sets `calign with current edge` if you prefer. The basic reason the tree isn't symmetric is because the children at this level are not equal in size, though. For symmetry, you need to make them equal in size.

Comment: Switched accepted answer, since if I did this today I would choose this approach :)

Answer (score 8):

The main problem is that your styles for the edges should be applied to the `child` commands not the `node` ones.  This is what I show in the second solution.  Probably better is styling the levels.  I'll give this first.

## Styling the levels

[image: Sample with level styles]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style={minimum size=4mm, inner sep=0.5mm},
  level 1/.style={every child/.style={edge from parent/.style={draw,dashed}}},
  level 2/.style={every child/.style={edge from parent/.style={draw,solid}}},
  level 4/.style={every child/.style={edge from
  parent/.style={draw,dashed}},sibling distance=5mm},
  normal/.style={circle,draw,solid},
  acc/.style={circle,thick,solid,draw=green!50,fill=green!2},
  rej/.style={circle,thick,solid,draw=red!50,fill=red!20},
  semithick]

  \node (root) {}
    child[level distance=11mm] { node[normal] {x}
      child {node[acc] {x1}
        child { node[normal] {} child child}
        child { node[normal] {} child child}
      }
      child {node[rej] {x2} }
      child {node[normal] {x3}
        child {node[normal] {} child }
        child {node[acc] {} child child }
        child {node[normal] {} child child child}
      }
  }; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This assumes cut off at uniform depth.  The style for level 2 is inherited by lower levels, so you specify styles for the first, second and last levels. If the cut off is not at uniform depth, you can instead write children on the last level as

```
child { edge from parent[dashed] }
```

producing a descending dashed line.

## Style on child

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style={minimum size=4mm, inner sep=0.5mm},
  normal/.style={circle,draw},
  invis/.style={draw=none},
  border/.style={ edge from parent/.style={dashed,draw} },
  normaledge/.style={ edge from parent/.style={solid,draw}},
  acc/.style={circle,thick,draw=green!50,fill=green!2},
  rej/.style={circle,thick,draw=red!50,fill=red!20},
  semithick]

  \node[invis] (root) {}
    child[level distance=11mm,border] { node[normal] {x}
      child[normaledge] {node[acc] {x1}
        child[border] {node {} }
        child[border] {node {} }
        child[border] {node {} }
      }
      child[normaledge] {node[rej] {x2} }
      child[normaledge] {node[normal] {x3}
        child[border] {node[invis] {} }
        child[border] {node[invis] {} }
        child[border] {node[invis] {} }
      }
  }; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I have introduced a `normaledge` style for edges that are not borders.

Comment: This looks pretty good, although I was precisely trying to avoid setting the `border` style on the topmost child, since that propagates down the tree, requiring the "extra work" of writing `normaledge` everywhere. Still, I can live with this. One last request, would it be possible to make the outlines of nodes x1 and x3 **not** dashed? I guess I could change the styles used in `node` and "override" the dashed style (but how?)

Comment: Nevermind, I already inferred how to do that from your example. Thanks a lot :)
One last thing I would like to know: since my code compiled, it must be syntactically correct to pass the style to the node - what was its effect, if not the one I was looking for?

Comment: I have updated my answer with another solution which may well be simpler to use.  In your original syntax `tikz` recognized the style command but had nothing to apply it to  (no edges of this type inside the node).

Comment: I understand know, edges are inherent to `child` since the `node`s could very well used to define a general graph... thanks for further insight into this. And kudos for a (imho) very elegant and flexible solution!

Comment: One last question, in case you still have the patience: Why is it necessary to append `solid` into the `acc` and `rej` styles? (I found out I get dashed nodes if I omit, but why?) Isn't the `level` style specifically referring to `edge from parent` only? (it seems to me TikZ draws **all** lines down from a child with the child's style, which would be... unexpected)

Comment: What is executed is essentially the same as `\path[dashed,draw] (0,0) -- (1,1) node[circle,draw] {x};` and the `dashed` gets inherited by the node.  Of course, you could the `solid` to your every node style.

Comment: Kind of defeats the purpose of setting the `dashed` option _specifically_ for the edges from parent, but I guess I should stop complaining and marvel at the awesomeness that is TikZ. Thank you for leading me on and pondering to my curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to use the [`istgame`](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) package. The `istgame` environment is just like the `tikzpicture` environment, so you can use any `macros and options` that work in the `tikzpicture` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}   

\begin{istgame}[font=\footnotesize]
\setistEllipseNodeStyle{6mm}
\xtdistance{15mm}{15mm}
\istroot[north](0)
  \istb[dashed] \endist
\istrooto(0){x}
  \istb \istb \istb \endist
\xtdistance{15mm}{10mm}
\istrooto(1)(0-1){x1}
  \istb[dashed] \istb[dashed] \istb[dashed] \endist
\istrooto(2)(0-2){x2}
  \endist
\istrooto(3)(0-3){x3}
  \istb[dashed] \istb[dashed] \istb[dashed] \endist
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In the updated version, `\tikzset' will replace `\tikzstyle'.